# How to isolate $\rho$

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to isolate $\rho$ from this equation here:

$$N=\frac{8.75}{34300}\left(\arcsin\left(\cos(\mu)\cdot\sin(\rho)\right)+\cos(\mu)\cdot\sin(\rho)\right)$$

I would much appreciate any answer to this.

Comment: Practical answer: numerically. I doubt there is any good way to do this algebraically.

Comment: Mathematica can solve this problem

Comment: @user2952272 This equation is very much non-linear for a question tagged linear-algebra :).